# Using for on register from a json file - Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I m not sure where is my error but i believe its with *for*. As it is, it print values from last record only. I tried to put print below statusInput = profile_data['_statusinput'] inside for but didn't work got:
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

**Code**

```
import json

with open('config/'+'config.json', 'r') as file:
    data: list = json.load(file)
    
    lista = data
for element in lista:
    print("")
    
    for alias_element in element:
        #print("Alias: " +alias_element)

        for result in element[alias_element]:
            profile_data = result
            aliasInput  = profile_data['_aliasinput']
            timesInput  = profile_data['_timesinput']
            idInput = profile_data['_idinput']
            statusInput = profile_data['_statusinput']
            

print(f" Values from register are {aliasInput}{timesInput}{idInput}{statusInput}")
```

**Result**

Last record value only.

*Example:*

```
Values from register are test2 12:45 19:20 888888 true
```

**Expected**

Print values of all records on the screen. Understanding it... Also d like to add a condition that print only if statusInput == true

*Example:*

```
Values from register are test 10:20 11111 true
Values from register are test1 11:50 99999 true
Values from register are test2 12:45 19:20 888888 true
```

Comment: Indentation error always means that you either didn't place indents correctly in order for the code to compile, _or_ you have both regular indents and spaces used in one file.

Comment: Thanks for replying, is it my case?

Comment: Most likely. Try changing every four spaces with an indent or something to make it one type of indent.

Comment: I didn't got it bro...